# FancyBox - Jquery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am using fancyBox plugin  and integrated example7 multiple times on my page, works fine in firefox but in ie 6 when i click on any image other than first it goes to download that image rather than pop up.Please help very urgent.

My Code is

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function() 
 { 
    $("a#example7").fancybox({ 'titlePosition' : 'inside' }); 
 });
 </script>
```

My HTML is

```
<a id="example7" href="./example/7_b.jpg" rel="Main Headline One" title="This is test.">
  <img src="./example/7_s.jpg" />
</a>
```

Comment: Post some code as urgent as u are to get solution as urgent as you want..

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("a#example7").fancybox({
    'titlePosition' : 'inside'
   });

  });
 </script><a id="example7" href="./example/7_b.jpg" rel="Main Headline One" title="This is test."><img  src="./example/7_s.jpg" /></a><a id="example7" href="./example/7_b.jpg" rel="Main Headline One" title="This is test."><img  src="./example/7_s.jpg" /></a>

Comment: Sol i have added the head script for example i am using and multiple a tags for the same.Please review and ask for any thing else you need from my end. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: You're lucky this is doing anything at all. IDs are unique, if you want to cut and paste code repeatedly, at least change the number 7 to something new each time. Also, please put the code in your post, not a comment, and format it.

Comment: Yup.. @Sinetheta You are absolutely correct. At the same time there is no such effect is built in Fancybox for exampl7 id here http://fancybox.net/howto.. They are using Class names..  Please read their documentation completely. I have used fancybox in one of my projects and it worked like a charm.

Comment: So you mean if i use class instead of id it will work in fine?

Comment: @Jos Yes use class like example6,example5 etc.. And then invoke fancybox.. That will work

Comment: @Jos http://jsfiddle.net/KwyQE/ have a look at this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding Same ID to different elements and trying to use effect that is not available in Fancybox.  Instead use class I have used in this fiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/KwyQE/
```

Hope it helps